# Javascript Regex and Internet Explorer 8 misreading

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hi all
I'm trying to make some javascript Regex compatible with IE8. Below:

```
/\/string\/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})\.[^]{1,3}($|&)/
/\/string\/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})($|&)/
```

The first one was not parsed (expecting ' ] ' at the end) until I added brackets between 'cod=' and ' } '. Then it worked.
Even very similar, the second Regex is still not working and IE8 seems to expect ' ) ' at the end of whatever. Why?
These expressions are then called as this:

```
var Reg1 = new RegExp("\/string\/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})\.[^]{1,3}($|&)");
var Reg2 = new RegExp("\/string\/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})($|&)");
switch(true) {
  case Reg1.test(string):
    ...    
    break;
  case Reg2.test(string):
    ...    
    break;
}
```

I must run the second Regex too.
In case I'm thinking about some jQuery stuff if may help.
Thanks for supporting.

Comment: You declare the regexps as objects, and pass them as objects to `RegExp`. You should pass them as strings, I think. `/string/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})[.][^]{1,3}($|&)` and `/string/.*(cod=[^]{4,5})($|&)`. You should either pass a string to the RegExp constructor, or use the regex literal syntax, but not both.

Comment: Thx @stribizhev but I'm just passing Regex as strings to constructors. In my question I put Regex alone and use replacing dots in the obj example to make expressions more clear to you. Literally I'm doing: new RegExp("\/string\/.*....."); as you expect

Comment: Hi, I solved by changing Regexes like below:                                              var Reg1 = new RegExp("\/string\/.*cod=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}\.[A-Z0-9]{1,3}($|&)");
var Reg2 = new RegExp("\/string\/.*cod=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}($|&)");                                   Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to escape `/` when passing a string to the RegExp constructor.